# Datatables: Clearing search field and not triggering search on column resort

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

We are using Datatables with the "serverSide" setting. Pagination, sorting, and searching all work swimmingly by themselves, but trying to sort on a column after a search has been performed causes an issue on the backend (our search engine defaults to search ranks and also aliases table names).

The current solution I have is to clear out the search field (i.e. reset the search) on a column reorder:

```
.on("order.dt", function(e) {
  $(this).DataTable().search("");
})
```

That works...okay, but the reorder only takes effect on the second column reorder. It seems data reordering triggers both an "order.dt" and a "search.dt" events.

Is there a way I can, on a reorder, clear the search before sending the reorder to the backend?

Alternatively, is there a way to determine if it's a reorder and not an actual search?

Comment: I have used the `draw()` function for a similar kind of server-side-rendered data-based DataTable for almost on every action. Maybe you can have a look at it:
https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()

Comment: Thanks, @vahdet, but redrawing the page isn't the issue here. Clicking on a table's headings sends both a search and a sort event. I need to ensure that search event doesn't send the value in the search field. That should only be sent on an actual search or a change of pagination.